# parse and strptime not transforming my dates in panda

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing

I am trying to get dates in my dataframe to be standard `timestamp`.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
747        August 1,2019
587           12-06-2019
347           04-09-2019
709          July 9,2019
135            20/2/2019
```

Parser seems to do nothing.

```py
df['registration_date'] = df['registration_date'].astype(str)

for date in df['registration_date']:
    try:
        date = parse(date)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Variations don't work:

```py
date = parse(date, fuzzy=True)
date = parse(date, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
date = parse(date, fuzzy_with_tokens=False)
```

And `strptime` doesn't work either:

```py
for date in df['registration_date']:
    try:                                                                                                        
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d,%Y')
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the `parse()` function come from? Where are you getting your data in the first place, it might be possible to format the dates earlier in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `df.registration_date = pd.to_datetime(df.registration_date)`.

Fortunately, `pd.to_datetime` is clever enough to recognize the date format
in each case and converts it properly (at least for your sample data).

**Note about types:**

If you then run `df.info()` you will see the type of this column
as *datetime64[ns]*. But if you read an **individual** value, e.g.
from the first row: `df.loc[0, 'registration_date']` you will get
*Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00')*, so individual values are
just of *Timestamp* type.

Comment: When you say _in each case_, do you mean this will work despite the nonhomogenous date formats?

Comment: I ran my code on the sample data provided, getting proper result. So it looks like this method checks the data format **individually** for particular case and then converts the source string according to the **current** format.

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to remember that it can do that.

Comment: using pd.to_datetime in above example will convert dates like 20/2/2019 (day first) to 2019-02-20 which may not be the intended behavior

Comment: Of course, even *to_datetime* has some limits concerning the built-in intelligence. As a matter of fact, there should be some basic principles, e.g. concerning the order of day / month / year part.